# Request Method not showing in chrome inspector

Tags: google-chrome, methods, tabs, inspector

**New Version:**
[image: method not present]

Previously method name used to show up besides Name in chrome inspector.In latest version of chrome it is missing any way to get it back?

**Old version:**

[image: Previous version]

Answer (score 1):

Got it
Just needed to right click and select options to show